# How to make VLC skip back/forward 5 seconds without lag

Tags: vlc-media-player

When I am watching a YouTube video I can skip forward/back 5 seconds with a single key press and the video instantly is able to play at the skipped ahead time.

When I used the now discontinued Media Player Classic I was able to do the same thing, skip forward/back and the video would play instantly when I skipped.

But in VLC if I skip forward/back 5 seconds it takes almost an additional 5 seconds before the video starts to play again.

I tried changing the setting `Tools > Preferences > Show Settings > All > Input/Codecs > Advanced > File Caching = 60000` which changed it from taking 5 seconds to play the video after skipping to 4 seconds.

I don't understand what setting to change. It is not a hardware issue since two other pieces of software are able to do it flawlessly with default settings and I don't see any solution or anyone with the same issue on Google

Is it a bug that I should report? Or a setting?

Comment: Though development for Media Player Classic, Home Cinema (MPC-HC) has been stopped by the original authors, it continues at https://github.com/clsid2/mpc-hc/releases, and is current at v.1.9.16 and is continually improving. Feel free to use MPC-HC for its excellent video features, as well as VLC.

Comment: VLC playback & skip is directly related to how busy/full your drive is & its seek speed. Skipping on an old rusty iron HDD is factors slower than an SSD. If your machine is busy, or using a lot of paging, then your speed will also suffer badly. As we have none of that information, I can't provide an accurate answer. Generally, a low cache size will make seek faster, at the expense of smooth playback. This is what I have set on my Mac, but I couldn't say if using the same parameters on a totally different machine would work - https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0271.png

Comment: @Tetsujin that would make sense if it happend on youtube as well, but youtube skips flawlessly

Comment: @DrMoishePippik thanks. the official website isn't updated with the latest releases which confused me

Comment: Youtube isn't reading from your hard drive.

Comment: @Tetsujin but network is way slower than read from SSD, there must be higher cache pull to RAM option to fix this on VLC, isn't it?

Comment: @AnimeshSahu - I'm not seeing how that differs from what I said.

Comment: @Tetsujin YouTube wishes it was reading from your hard drive. Near instantaneous seeking of YouTube videos is _only_ possible because typical web browsers cache the video in memory or storage. If the journey across 20 inches of copper from disk platter to CPU is somehow slower on your Mac than networking through 200 miles of backhaul infrastructure to the nearest CDN node, you have bigger problems to worry about.

Comment: @TiberiumFusion -  that's not what I said at all. Please re-read.